# Control layers Icon according to feature type (properties)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

**Please read first understand then react.** 
People nowadays give negative mark without know the actual issue.

**if You have any more information need please ask me.**

**leaflet Version: Leaflet 1.0.2,**
*I am using map-box plugin here for better CDN access.

I have successfully crate control layer group and custom Circle Marker group using GeoJSON.

This is source:

```js
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZG9zcyIsImEiOiI1NFItUWs4In0.-9qpbOfE3jC68WDUQA1Akg';

var map = L.mapbox.map('mapbox', 'mapbox.light').setView([22.9867569, 87.8549755], 9);

var baselayer = {};


var initialContent = {};

var myGeometry = JSON.stringify({
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "pname": "66_marker",
      "action": "B",
      "name": "AAA",
      "photo": "",
      "comment": "",
      "fac_type": "",
      "val_6": 1,
      "val_7": 333333,
      "val_8": "",
      "val_9": "",
      "val_10": "",
      "val_11": "",
      "val_12": "",
      "val_13": "",
      "val_14": "",
      "val_15": "",
      "val_16": "",
      "val_17": "",
      "val_18": "",
      "val_19": "",
      "val_20": "",
      "id": 66,
      "user_id": 1
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [88.266906738281, 22.793907258499]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "pname": "73_marker",
      "action": "A",
      "name": "WW",
      "photo": "",
      "comment": "",
      "fac_type": "",
      "val_6": 1,
      "val_7": 333333,
      "val_8": "",
      "val_9": "",
      "val_10": "",
      "val_11": "",
      "val_12": "",
      "val_13": "",
      "val_14": "",
      "val_15": "",
      "val_16": "",
      "val_17": "",
      "val_18": "",
      "val_19": "",
      "val_20": "",
      "id": 73,
      "user_id": 1
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [88.360290527344, 22.692586244731]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "pname": "78_marker",
      "action": "b",
      "name": "BBB",
      "photo": "",
      "comment": "",
      "fac_type": "",
      "val_6": 1,
      "val_7": 333333,
      "val_8": "",
      "val_9": "",
      "val_10": "",
      "val_11": "",
      "val_12": "",
      "val_13": "",
      "val_14": "",
      "val_15": "",
      "val_16": "",
      "val_17": "",
      "val_18": "",
      "val_19": "",
      "val_20": "",
      "id": 78,
      "user_id": 1
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [88.887634277344, 22.872379306788]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "pname": "83_marker",
      "action": "Q",
      "name": "SSS",
      "photo": "",
      "comment": "",
      "fac_type": "",
      "val_6": 1,
      "val_7": 333333,
      "val_8": "",
      "val_9": "",
      "val_10": "",
      "val_11": "",
      "val_12": "",
      "val_13": "",
      "val_14": "",
      "val_15": "",
      "val_16": "",
      "val_17": "",
      "val_18": "",
      "val_19": "",
      "val_20": "",
      "id": 83,
      "user_id": 1
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [88.689880371094, 22.978623970385]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "pname": "88_marker",
      "action": "A",
      "name": "WW",
      "photo": "",
      "comment": "",
      "fac_type": 1,
      "val_6": 1,
      "val_7": 333333,
      "val_8": "",
      "val_9": "",
      "val_10": "",
      "val_11": "",
      "val_12": "",
      "val_13": "",
      "val_14": "",
      "val_15": "",
      "val_16": "",
      "val_17": "",
      "val_18": "",
      "val_19": "",
      "val_20": "",
      "id": 88,
      "user_id": 1
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [88.401489257812, 22.935630216775]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "pname": "93_marker",
      "action": "C",
      "name": "qqq",
      "photo": "",
      "comment": "",
      "fac_type": 1,
      "val_6": 1,
      "val_7": 333333,
      "val_8": "",
      "val_9": "",
      "val_10": "",
      "val_11": "",
      "val_12": "",
      "val_13": "",
      "val_14": "",
      "val_15": "",
      "val_16": "",
      "val_17": "",
      "val_18": "",
      "val_19": "",
      "val_20": "",
      "id": 93,
      "user_id": 1
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [88.547058105469, 22.85719470097]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "pname": "98_marker",
      "action": "AA",
      "name": "QQ",
      "photo": "",
      "comment": "",
      "fac_type": 1,
      "val_6": 1,
      "val_7": 22222,
      "val_8": "",
      "val_9": "",
      "val_10": "",
      "val_11": "",
      "val_12": "",
      "val_13": "",
      "val_14": "",
      "val_15": "",
      "val_16": "",
      "val_17": "",
      "val_18": "",
      "val_19": "",
      "val_20": "",
      "id": 98,
      "user_id": 1
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [88.118591308594, 22.791375149054]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "pname": "62_marker",
      "action": "GG",
      "name": "Kuntal",
      "photo": "1477902102_Street_-_Kolkata_2011-07-27_00417.jpg",
      "comment": "This is Kolkata",
      "fac_type": 8,
      "val_6": 1,
      "val_7": 9830264337,
      "val_8": "HH",
      "val_9": 9754875,
      "val_10": "d@ajdh.com",
      "val_11": "",
      "val_12": "",
      "val_13": "",
      "val_14": "",
      "val_15": "",
      "val_16": "",
      "val_17": "",
      "val_18": "",
      "val_19": "",
      "val_20": "",
      "id": 62,
      "user_id": 1
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [87.896118164062, 22.748322097622]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "pname": "77_polygon",
      "action": 1,
      "name": "",
      "photo": "",
      "comment": "",
      "fac_type": "",
      "val_6": "",
      "val_7": "",
      "val_8": "",
      "val_9": "",
      "val_10": "",
      "val_11": "",
      "val_12": "",
      "val_13": "",
      "val_14": "",
      "val_15": "",
      "val_16": "",
      "val_17": "",
      "val_18": "",
      "val_19": "",
      "val_20": "",
      "id": 77,
      "user_id": 1
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [88.302773237228, 22.684419907565],
          [88.30274105072, 22.684122940681],
          [88.303438425064, 22.683954659161],
          [88.303513526917, 22.684281323099],
          [88.303191661835, 22.684311019782],
          [88.302773237228, 22.684419907565]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "pname": "94_polygon",
      "action": 2,
      "name": "",
      "photo": "",
      "comment": "",
      "fac_type": "",
      "val_6": "",
      "val_7": "",
      "val_8": "",
      "val_9": "",
      "val_10": "",
      "val_11": "",
      "val_12": "",
      "val_13": "",
      "val_14": "",
      "val_15": "",
      "val_16": "",
      "val_17": "",
      "val_18": "",
      "val_19": "",
      "val_20": "",
      "id": 94,
      "user_id": 1
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [88.305047750473, 22.685221714938],
          [88.304886817932, 22.68493464864],
          [88.305455446243, 22.684598087387],
          [88.305659294128, 22.684974244027],
          [88.305047750473, 22.685221714938]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "pname": "69_marker",
      "action": "y",
      "name": "",
      "photo": "",
      "comment": "",
      "fac_type": 1,
      "val_6": "",
      "val_7": "",
      "val_8": "",
      "val_9": "",
      "val_10": "",
      "val_11": "",
      "val_12": "",
      "val_13": "",
      "val_14": "",
      "val_15": "",
      "val_16": "",
      "val_17": "",
      "val_18": "",
      "val_19": "",
      "val_20": "",
      "id": 69,
      "user_id": 1
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [88.304752707481, 22.683890316173]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "pname": "73_marker",
      "action": "r",
      "name": "",
      "photo": "",
      "comment": "",
      "fac_type": 1,
      "val_6": "",
      "val_7": "",
      "val_8": "",
      "val_9": "",
      "val_10": "",
      "val_11": "",
      "val_12": "",
      "val_13": "",
      "val_14": "",
      "val_15": "",
      "val_16": "",
      "val_17": "",
      "val_18": "",
      "val_19": "",
      "val_20": "",
      "id": 73,
      "user_id": 1
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [88.304173350334, 22.684276373652]
    }
  }]
});

var myGeoJSON = JSON.parse(myGeometry);

var geoJsonGroup = L.geoJson(myGeoJSON);

var categories = {},
  fac_type;

var myStyle = {
  fillOpacity: 1,
  stroke: false,
  weight: 1,
  opacity: 1,
  fill: true,
  clickable: true
};

var geoJsonGroup = new L.geoJson(myGeoJSON, {

  style: function(feature) {
    switch (feature.properties.pname) {
      case '66_marker':
        return {
          color: "yellow"
        };
      case '73_marker':
        return {
          color: "blue"
        };
      case '62_marker':
        return {
          color: "redMarker"
        };
      case '77_polygon':
        return {
          color: "red"
        };
    }
  },

  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, myStyle);

  },

  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    var layers = layer;


    var initialContent = document.createElement("div");
    initialContent.className = "content-scroll6";
    initialContent.innerHTML = "<table class='table table-striped'><tr><td>POI_NAME</td><td>" + feature.properties.name + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>FAC_TYPE</td><td><a id='fac_type'></a></td></tr>" + "<tr><td>SUBCAT</td><td>" + feature.properties.val_6 + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>PH_NUMBER</td><td>" + feature.properties.val_7 + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>HNO</td><td>" + feature.properties.val_8 + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>POSTCODE</td><td>" + feature.properties.val_9 + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>MAIL</td><td>" + feature.properties.val_10 + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>STR_NM</td><td>" + feature.properties.val_11 + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>PHOTO</td><td ><img src='uploads/" + feature.properties.photo + "' class='inImg'></td></tr>" + "<tr><td>COMMENT</td><td>" + feature.properties.comment + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>URL</td><td>" + feature.properties.val_12 + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>SUB_LOC</td><td>" + feature.properties.val_13 + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>LOCALITY</td><td>" + feature.properties.val_14 + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>Val 15</td><td>" + feature.properties.val_15 + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>Val 16</td><td>" + feature.properties.val_16 + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>Val 17</td><td>" + feature.properties.val_17 + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>Val 18</td><td>" + feature.properties.val_18 + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>Val 19</td><td>" + feature.properties.val_19 + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>Val 20</td><td>" + feature.properties.val_20 + "</td></tr></table>";

    layer.bindPopup(initialContent);



    fac_type = feature.properties.pname;
    // Initialize the category array if not already set.
    if (typeof categories[fac_type] === "undefined") {
      categories[fac_type] = [];
    }
    categories[fac_type].push(layer);


  }

}).addTo(map);



var overlaysObj = {},
  categoryName,
  categoryArray,
  categoryLG;

for (categoryName in categories) {

  categoryArray = categories[categoryName];
  categoryLG = L.layerGroup(categoryArray);
  categoryLG.categoryName = categoryName;
  overlaysObj[categoryName] = categoryLG;

}

// Create an empty LayerGroup that will be used to emulate adding / removing all categories.
var allPointsLG = L.layerGroup();
overlaysObj["All Points"] = allPointsLG;

var control = L.control.layers(baselayer, overlaysObj, {
  collapsed: false
}).addTo(map);


// Make sure the Layers Control checkboxes are kept in sync with what is on map.
// For some reason this control does not sync its checkboxes with the map state by itself, whereas it does with Leaflet 0.7.x?
map.on("overlayadd overlayremove", function(event) {
  var layer = event.layer,
    layerCategory;

  if (layer === allPointsLG) {
    if (layer.notUserAction) {
      // allPointsLG has been removed just to sync its state with the fact that at least one
      // category is not shown. This event does not come from a user un-ticking the "All points" checkbox.
      layer.notUserAction = false;
      return;
    }
    // Emulate addition / removal of all category LayerGroups when allPointsLG is added / removed.
    for (var categoryName in overlaysObj) {
      if (categoryName !== "All Points") {
        if (event.type === "overlayadd") {
          overlaysObj[categoryName].addTo(map);
        } else {
          map.removeLayer(overlaysObj[categoryName]);
        }
      }
    }
    control._update();
  } else if (layer.categoryName && layer.categoryName in overlaysObj) {
    if (event.type === "overlayadd") {
      // Check if all categories are shown.
      for (var categoryName in overlaysObj) {
        layerCategory = overlaysObj[categoryName];
        if (categoryName !== "All Points" && !layerCategory._map) {
          // At least one category is not shown, do nothing.
          return;
        }
      }
      allPointsLG.addTo(map);
      control._update();
    } else if (event.type === "overlayremove" && allPointsLG._map) {
      // Remove allPointsLG as at least one category is not shown.
      // But register the fact that this is purely for updating the checkbox, not a user action.
      allPointsLG.notUserAction = true;
      map.removeLayer(allPointsLG);
      control._update();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body,
#mapbox {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.2/mapbox.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.2/mapbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div id="mapbox"></div>
</body>
```

**What I Want to make is :
1. Customise Icon for markers not different colour as you see now.

2. Add different Icon on layer Control. 
Example Image:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/) for creating custom leaflet markers.

The idea is that rather than converting the marker point to L.circleMarker, you can create a marker with custom icon image.

Since you will have multiple icons it sounds like, it would be best to create an icon class:

```
var myIcon = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
        iconSize:     [38, 95],
        iconAnchor:   [22, 94],
        popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
    }
});
```

Then when you instantiate the icon, you can set your custom icon image.

```
var firstIcon = new myIcon({iconUrl: 'first-icon.png'}),
    anotherIcon = new myIcon({iconUrl: 'another-icon.png'}),
    yetAnotherIcon = new myIcon({iconUrl: 'tet-another.png'});


 pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
      if(feature.properties.pname == '66_marker'){
         return L.marker(latlng, {icon: firstIcon});
       } else if (feature.properties.pname == '73_marker'){
         return L.marker(latlng, {icon: anotherIcon});
       }
  }
```

To create a custom icon for layer control, you can create icon classes in your css. When you add the layer to layer control you can add in your icon.

```
overlaysObj[categoryName] = '<span class="custom-icon"></span>' + categoryLG;
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, you are great, just little change complete my code:
overlaysObj[categoryName] = '<span class="custom-icon"></span>' + categoryLG;

To 

overlaysObj["<span class='custom_" + categoryLG.categoryName + "'></span>" + categoryName] =  categoryLG;